# Expand bash alias inline VScode's integrated bash terminal

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-subsystem-for-linux, alias

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> is the default key binding for doing an inline bash alias expansion, and it works fine if I open a WSL terminal outside of VScode.

However, It does not work in the integrated WSL terminal in VScode, and I don't seem to find a way to expand a bash alias within the integrated terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `terminal.integrated.sendKeybindingsToShell` setting, which controls whether keybinds are sent to the terminal and shell. Since <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> is not defined by default, that's all that should be required.

See [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/advanced#_keybinding-and-the-shell).

Comment: Not sure why this was migrated, it fits SU as well, although this has more VSCode questions.

Comment: I enabled the `terminal.integrated.sendKeybindingsToShell` as you suggested, but `ctrl` + `Alt` + `E` is still not expanding a bash alias in the integrated terminal.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific then. Is that bound by you in your config? If so, to what? What's the terminal profile that's being used?

Comment: it's not bound at all. I am using WSL as my integrated terminal. I changed a few things but let me know how I can make my question more clear.

Comment: restart VSC for changes to take effect